# Set default CMS page layout

Tags: layout, cms

I've got **plenty** of CMS pages to add. Each of them should use '2 colums with right column' layout. The default is '1 column'.

How can I change the **default setting**?

Tried this in local.xml:

```
<cms_page>
    <label>CMS Pages (All)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

but it didn't work.

I know I can do this **individually** for every page, but I want to set the **default setting**. So I don't have to set it 100 times for every single page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adding this in config.xml solved the issue:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <one_column module="page" translate="label">
                    <is_default>0</is_default>
                </one_column>
                <!-- default page for new cms pages -->
                <two_columns_right module="page" translate="label">
                    <is_default>1</is_default>
                </two_columns_right>
            </layouts>
          </page>
```

Comment: cool answer.. +1 for this.. it would be nice if we add the link that helped you to resolve this issue.

Comment: where is config.xml file located?

Answer (score 1):

Magento has this facility built-in. You just want to use that. For this, login into admin section of your site, go to `CMS > Pages > [Select your CMS Page] > Design` tab and choose `2column-right` layout from there.

If the CMS Page has any custom layout set in the above section, then layout update that you have mentioned is never going to apply, since your changes has overwritten by the in-built facility that I have described above. So use the default feature. Simple and elegant.

### EDIT

Your layout update is not working because, all of your cms pages updates that you have done through the layout update handle `cms_page` are overwritten by it's *higher levels*<sup>1</sup> updates. Most probably, all of your CMS Pages has their own root template which set via backend (you can find this setting at  `CMS > Pages >[any cms page] > Design > layout`). If you want to overcome this higher level layout update, the only possible way is listening to a special event **[`cms_page_render`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php#L107)**.

**Event Registration**

File : `app\code\local\Namespace\Module\etc\config.xml`

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <cms_page_render>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_module>
                        <class>rkt_seo/observer</class>
                        <method>changeCMSPageTemplate</method>
                    </namespace_module>
                </observers>
            </cms_page_render>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <namespace_module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
            </namespace_module>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Observer**

File : `app\code\local\Namespace\Module\Model\Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
    const PAGE_EMPTY       = 'empty';
    const ONE_COLUMN       = 'one_column';
    const TWO_COLUMN_RIGHT = 'two_columns_right';
    const TWO_COLUMN_LEFT  = 'two_columns_left';
    const THREE_COLUMN     = 'three_columns';

    public function changeCMSPageTemplate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        $update = $action->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        $helper = $action->getLayout()->helper('page/layout');

        $pageLayout = $helper->getCurrentPageLayout();
        if ($pageLayout !== false) {
            $update->removeHandle($pageLayout->getLayoutHandle());
        }
        $helper->applyHandle(self::TWO_COLUMN_RIGHT);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Theory**

`cms_page_render` is fired after applying CMS Page specific page layout handle. In your case `page_one_column` layout update handle will get added. What we need is, we need to remove this layout update handle and then add our own page layout update handle, ie `page_two_column_right`. Observer will doing that job here.

**Note 1:** This update will affect all CMS Pages irrespective of the value at the **layout** section of a cms page (backend) under `Design` tab.

**Note 2 :** Since this observer overwrite admin layout template functionality, the only way to overwrite the changes that we have done via observer is using custom layout xml section comes under `Design` tab of each cms page. That means if you need to use a special page layout other than `2 column right` for a specific CMS Page, then you should use the above section to do that.

**Note 3 :** If you have further doubts on how to setup the module, then **[*you can use this*](https://gist.github.com/progammer-rkt/dfdc666dc82a7335644d)**.

---

<sup>1</sup> : Higher level may be a layout update handle which is process after `cms_page` (eg: `cms_page_view` or `cms_index_index`, `page_one_column` etc). It also includes root templates that we set via admin section (ie under `CMS > Pages >[any cms page] > Design > layout`). It can also be the specific layout updates that you have specified in the xml section of a CMS Page.

Comment: Rajeev, I know I can do this INDIVIDUALLY, but I want to set THE DEFAULT setting. So I don't have to set it 100 times for every single page.

Comment: @mati current code is not working ?

Comment: No, still "1 column" is used as default every time I create new CMS page :(

Comment: @mati  see my update

Comment: Rajeev, thank you for your effort! This is great. I investigated more and found much simpler solution, so I will add it and mark it as accepted. But your edit is very valuable for telling the way Magento works!

Comment: @mati okay.. cool.. let me know after you put an answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you will need to update the layout in magento's back end. By default it will use your `layout.xml` to apply the updates, However if the cms page in the database has something different magento will use that as per its fallback.

You can change a CMS layout under `CMS > Pages > CMS_PAGE > Design` and choose the `layout` desired.

Comment: "you will need to update the layout in magento's back end" - I don't want to update this for every one of 100+ pages. How can I set new default, so no manual update for **every page** is needed?

Comment: You could create an upgrade script to loop over the cms pages and set the templates

Comment: That could work too, but people who'll add articles in the future are beyound the concept of layout, so the script would need to be run many times... Can it be done [like in that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5846393/60207)? I tried to locate the correct xml for this setting, but no luck.

Comment: You could look at looping over them initially and then maybe look at using an observer such as 'cms_page_prepare_save` or `$this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before` to change the tempalte before it is saved.